# Animation beyond Fragment borders

Tags: android, animation, fragment, android-animation, objectanimator

I have a very simple `Fragment`. Its view is a `RelativeLayout` with a single `ImageView`.

I want to animate that `ImageView` using `ObjectAnimator`'s `TRANSLATE_X` property. The problem is that the image does not go beyond the border of the **Fragment** while animating.

Setting **`ClipChildren=false`** on the `RelativeLayout` **does NOT help** (although it always worked for me on non-Fragments).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately nothing worked.

Fixed it by animating the fragment itself rather than the image inside.